# Ubuntu won't boot up when on battery, only when plugged in

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, power-management, battery

My Ubuntu screen does not open in battery mode; it just loads a black screen.

It works if a power cable is plugged in.

My laptop is ASUS TUF Gaming fx505 dd with dual-boot, UEFI-enabled.

The NVIDIA driver is properly installed and working so I don't believe it's a driver issue.

Output of `nvidia-smi`:

[image: nvidia terminal]

The nVidia Dialog shows:

[image: nvidia dialog]

I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux.

Comment: Does the other OS boot ? Or don't you even come to GRUB ?

Comment: Is SecureBoot enabled or disabled in the BIOS menu?

Comment: Maybe this is too easy, but could this be as simple as a battery problem? What happens if you boot into Ubuntu with the power cable connected and then remove it once fully booted? And does your other OS load as suggested by @Soren A?

Comment: @SorenA yes Windows boot in battery

Comment: @NateT SecureBoot is enabled

Comment: @Will other OS boot up in battery and there is no battery problem. Once I boot in after that it work fine even if power cable is not connected. I guess its some issue with Ubuntu but I'm not able to figure it out. I have seen many people with same issue who all are having Ryzen 5 3500 processor like me

Comment: I have the same issue with Ubuntu Mate 20.04 - ASUS laptop with Ryzen 5 and Nvidia offloaded graphics - interestingly sometimes it booted also on battery - mistakenly forgot to plug in - but mostly only to black screen. When removing power cable after successful boot everything is fine. Any ideas which logs to look at?